# Apply bootstrap styles to a DayPickerInput in react-day-picker

Tags: css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the react-day-picker library to have a calendar in my react form but the input is not following the bootstrap styles of the "form-control" className, and I want the input has the same size of the top inputs as the image

```
               <div className="form-group">
                    <div className="row">
                        <label className="text-light col-lg-12" htmlFor="fecha">Nacimiento</label>
                    </div>
                    <DayPickerInput id="fecha" inputProps={{ className: 'form-control' }} value={this.selectedDay} onDayChange={this.handleDayChange}/>
                </div>
```

[image: I want the input has the same size of the top input]